# Change week of year value based on conditional data in other column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, lubridate

I have the following DF (this is a subset):

```
structure(list(First.Name = c(6003L, 6003L, 6003L, 6003L, 6003L, 
6004L, 6004L, 6004L, 6004L, 6001L, 6001L, 6001L, 6001L, 6002L, 
6002L, 6002L, 6002L, 6002L, 6003L, 6003L, 6003L, 6003L, 6004L, 
6004L, 6004L), Intervention = c("PRE", "PRE", "PRE", "PRE", "PRE", 
"PRE", "PRE", "PRE", "PRE", NA, NA, NA, NA, "PRE", "PRE", "PRE", 
"PRE", "PRE", "PRE", "PRE", "PRE", "PRE", "PRE", "PRE", "PRE"
), WeekofYear = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), groups = structure(list(
    First.Name = 6001:6004, .rows = list(10:13, 14:18, c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L), c(6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 23L, 
    24L, 25L))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

That looks like:

```
# A tibble: 25 x 3
# Groups:   First.Name [4]
   First.Name Intervention WeekofYear
        <int> <chr>             <dbl>
 1       6003 PRE                   7
 2       6003 PRE                   7
 3       6003 PRE                   7
 4       6003 PRE                   7
 5       6003 PRE                   8
 6       6004 PRE                   7
 7       6004 PRE                   7
 8       6004 PRE                   7
 9       6004 PRE                   7
10       6001 NA                    7
# ... with 15 more rows
```

My data spans several weeks, and I would like to summarize the data by name, then by week of year.
However, I would like to reset some of the week values based on the Intervention columns.

For example, ID 6003 has week 7 and 8 both labeled PRE intervention:

```
   First.Name Intervention WeekofYear
        <int> <chr>             <dbl>
4       6003 PRE                   7
5       6003 PRE                   8
```

I would like to set week 8 to 7 while the label is "PRE" in this case or set the other cases to the first week of that participant's data for anything labeled "PRE" (keeping in mind some labels are NA).

So example output:

```
# A tibble: 25 x 3
# Groups:   First.Name [4]
   First.Name Intervention WeekofYear
        <int> <chr>             <dbl>
 1       6003 PRE                   7
 2       6003 PRE                   7
 3       6003 PRE                   7
 4       6003 PRE                   7
 5       6003 PRE                   7
 6       6004 PRE                   7
 7       6004 PRE                   7
 8       6004 PRE                   7
 9       6004 PRE                   7
10       6001 NA                    7
# ... with 15 more rows
```

I have tried various forms of the following with no luck:

```
FinalDF %>% 
  group_by(First.Name) %>% 
  mutate(
    if(FinalDF$Intervention == "PRE") {
      WeekofYear = min(FinalDF$WeekofYear, na.rm=T)
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ifelse` or `case_when` or `replace` instead of `if/else` as `if/else` is not vectorized and expects a single input value and output a single boolean value

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
   group_by(First.Name) %>%
   mutate(WeekofYear = replace(WeekofYear, Intervention == 'PRE', min(WeekofYear)))
   #or with case_when
   # mutate(WeekofYear = case_when(Intervention == "PRE"~ min(WeekofYear), TRUE ~ WeekofYear))
```

Comment: Ah I was so close, thank you! ( I will accept the answer in 10min when stackoverflow allows)